# Regex for build gradle file in bash

Tags: regex, bash

I'm working on a CI and I need to update the version name of a file like this. Hence I'm pretending to use a regex.

So I'm working on a regex to change the version name to update the value versionName of the `flavor prod` only.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.app.helloworld"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 30

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    flavorDimensions "version"
    productFlavors {
        demo {
            // Assigns this product flavor to the "version" flavor dimension.
            // If you are using only one dimension, this property is optional,
            // and the plugin automatically assigns all the module's flavors to
            // that dimension.
            dimension "version"
            applicationIdSuffix ".demo"
            versionNameSuffix "-demo"
            versionCode 102312
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        pro {
            dimension "version"
            versionCode 102312
            versionName "1.0"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

My current regex is `(pro)(.*)((versionName) .*)` but I'm struggling with multiline patterns :(

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify what `bash` command you want to use to replace the `versionName` value. Here is a one-liner using `perl`, that does the replace on a short demo file:

```
$ cat props.conf
    replaceTest {
        demo {
            dimension "version"
            versionCode 102312
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        pro {
            dimension "version"
            versionCode 102312
            versionName "1.0"
        }
    }
$ perl -i -pe 'BEGIN{undef $/;} s/(\bpro +\{.*?versionName +)("[^"]*")/$1"2.0"/smg' props.conf
$ cat props.conf
    replaceTest {
        demo {
            dimension "version"
            versionCode 102312
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        pro {
            dimension "version"
            versionCode 102312
            versionName "2.0"
        }
    }
```

Explanation:

- `BEGIN{undef $/;}` - make perl search & replace multi-line
- `s///smg` - perl search & replace over multiple lines
- `(\bpro +\{.*?versionName +)` - first capture group making sure we catch to `pro`, not `demo`

  - `\bpro +\{` - expect `pro` surrounded by space, followed by `{`
  - `.*?` - non-greedily scan over anything
  - `versionName +` - expect `versionName` and 1+ space
- `("[^"]*")` - second capture group containing `"`, the version number, and `"`
- `$1"2.0"` - replace part: use `$1` for first capture group, specify new version string `"2.0"`

If you want to work on stdin and stdout, omit the `-i` perl switch.